# How to revoke 3rd-party apps Twitter integration on iOS 11?

Tags: iphone, ios, permission, twitter

I used to have some iOS apps that were authorized to access my Twitter account through the legacy Twitter integration feature in old iOS version. This feature is no longer available in iOS 11.

According to Twitter (https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/revoke-twitter-access-on-ios-app) :

> Note: Though you will see other specific apps like Twitter for iPhone
>   or Camera for iOS listed in your active connections, you cannot revoke
>   access to these individual apps; you have to revoke access for the
>   entire iOS integration.

How do I revoke those apps' access if all my devices are running iOS 11?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer to my own question.

"iOS integration" itself is actually listed among all those apps and it has a revoke button. Once you revoke this, all apps authorized through iOS integration will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You can revoke access to those apps from the Desktop or Mobile version of twitter only as iOS 11 does not have that feature anymore. Follow the instructions below.

1. Go to Settings -> Account
2. Go to Connected Apps under Data and permissions for all apps which you have given access (For Mobile)
3. Go to Apps (For Desktop)
4. Select the app you want to remove.
5. Select Revoke Access.

You should be able to do this for all the unwanted apps.

Comment: Under Data and permissions, I see only two sections: "Country" and "Your Twitter data".

Comment: @YuhaoZhang Go to Apps if you are using Desktop version. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I know the "Apps" section on Desktop version. But I can only see "revoke access" buttons for apps authorized through standard Twitter API. Although it does list apps authorized through iOS Twitter integration, there aren't any revoke buttons beside them, instead, it says "Learn how to revoke an iOS app." and points me to the Twitter help page I mentioned in OP.